# Bad results using auto.arima

Tags: r, forecasting

Im trying to use auto.arima function but it is not working properly. The code (edited):

```
dummydata <- c(-1.55993917397658, -1.17458854064119, -0.172676893969176, -0.301127105080973,
....
)
# Full data at http://pastebin.com/V93K30zG
aux_data <- ts(data = dummydata, frequency = 7)
plot(x=1:413, y=aux_data, type='l', xlim=c(1,440), ylim=c(-4,3))
# ARIMA
best_arima <- auto.arima(aux_data, ic="bic", allowdrift = FALSE)
# aux_pred <- predict(best_arima, n.ahead=14)
aux_pred <- forecast(best_arima, h=14)
pred_data <- aux_pred$mean
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x=c(414:427), y=pred_data, type='l', col="red", xlim=c(1,440), ylim=c(-4,3))
```

And the results are nonsense:

[image: 14 steps predition]

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: You should provide a working example of `aux_data`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune  How do you usually share files here in stackoverflow? Thanks.

Comment: Don't share the file. Just add a piece of the dataframe to the question `head(aux_data, 20)`

Comment: The data you plot is not the same as the data you pass to auto.arima(). Perhaps that's your problem. Also, use forecast() rather than predict() and try plotting the resulting forecast object.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've fixed the naming and changed to `forecast()` function, but no progress: the results are exactly the same. Check out the data from [here](http://pastebin.com/V93K30zG) to reproduce the example.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example where `auto.arima` makes a bad choice about the seasonal differencing. (A problem which is on my to do list: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast7-part-2/)

You can get better results as follows:

```
best_arima <- auto.arima(aux_data, D=1)
aux_pred <- forecast(best_arima, h=14)
plot(aux_pred, plot.conf=FALSE, fcol='red')
```

[image]